# Delete a row using allowed method from grails link in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.4.2. I have a form from where I can add , edit or delete any data or row. But from index I want to delete a single row on demand. For that I have added a link in my table cell for each row. But it is giving error no 405 which is `The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource`. Can anyone please help me on this ? Here are my index page below :

My index.gsp >>>

```
<table>
        <thead>
                <tr>                    
                    <g:sortableColumn property="address" title="${message(code: 'userInfo.address.label', default: 'Address')}" />                  
                    <g:sortableColumn property="name" title="${message(code: 'userInfo.name.label', default: 'Name')}" />
                    <g:sortableColumn property="name" title="${message(code: 'userInfo.name.label', default: 'Action')}" />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${userInfoInstanceList}" status="i" var="userInfoInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">                   
                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${userInfoInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: userInfoInstance, field: "address")}</g:link></td>                 
                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInfoInstance, field: "name")}</td>
                    <td><g:link action="delete" id="${userInfoInstance.id}">Delete</g:link></td>                    
                </tr>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are using "allowedMethods" inside your controller , like this

```
    static allowedMethods = [delete: "POST"]
```

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.2/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html

but when you use the link taglib you are making a GET request instead of POST

Comment: thanks for your reply. My allowed methods are like this `static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]`. My question is, can I use the delete: DELETE with g:link tag ?!!!

Comment: No, you can't. You have to either use AJAX or need to submit a form with DELETE method